# How to include all DLLs with my SDL2_mixer mingw application?

Tags: c++, static-linking, mingw-w64

I'm making a simple application which uses SDL2_mixer lib. I want to make my application ready for distribution, which I guess means I should include all the dependency DLLs with my application.

```
g++ -o bin/myapplication.exe build/src/main.o build/src/Sound_Mixer.o `sdl2-config --static-libs` -static-libstdc++ -lmingw32 -lSDL2_mixer
```

Whenever I try to run my application on another computer, I get an error popup saying `The code execution cannot proceed because libXYZ.dll was not found`.

I'm trying to just copy all the DLLs that pop up in the error message to my applications directory, but there seems to be so insanely many. I don't think I ever will finish copying all the libs.

Is there an efficient way to solve this? Is there a way to include all the necessary dependencies in my .exe file? Or should I be copying all the DLLs and keep it in the dir with my .exe? If so, how can I really determine all the DLLs that are needed?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the following are required with G++ version 8.x.
You should find them in the bin directory of your mingw distribution.

- libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll
- libstdc++-6.dll
- libwinpthread-1.dll

Comment: Thanks! But there is a lot more DLLs needed for SDL2_mixer. I started adding them one-by-one but after about 15 .dll files added it started getting very boring.

Comment: You should normally find the required DLLs for SDL2 in the package you have downloaded, along with the .a and/or .lib linking libraries. If there is no DLL in your package, whether you took the wrong one, or you have to build it yourself.